# Gtk TextView dynamic styling

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, gtk3

I have a textview widget and I can apply tags such as bold, underline etc.

```
    self.tags = {}
    self.tags['bold'] = self.textbuffer.create_tag("bold", weight=Pango.Weight.BOLD)
    self.tags['italic'] = self.textbuffer.create_tag("italic", style=Pango.Style.ITALIC)
    self.tags['underline'] = self.textbuffer.create_tag("underline", underline=Pango.Underline.SINGLE)
    self.tags['ubuntu'] = self.textbuffer.create_tag("ubuntu", family = "Ubuntu Mono")
    self.tags['size'] = self.textbuffer.create_tag("size", font_desc=Pango.FontDescription.from_string("32"))
```

The problem is with the last one, If I apply the font size tag, then the rest don't work.

The function that handles the `insert-text` signal is the following :

```
def insert_with_tags(self, buffer, start_iter, data, data_len):

    if data_len == 1:
        start_iter.backward_char()
    end = self.textbuffer.props.cursor_position
    end_iter = self.textbuffer.get_iter_at_offset(end)
    self.textbuffer.apply_tag(self.tags['size'], start_iter, end_iter)
    for tag in self.format_toolbar.buttons:
        if self.format_toolbar.buttons[tag].get_active():
            self.textbuffer.apply_tag(self.tags[tag], start_iter, end_iter)
```

If I remove the line that applies the font size everything works, but I want to let the user to be able to modify the font (here im testing it with just 1 font, but its the same when I add tags for the rest) while typing and not just modify it for the entire buffer.

Comment: Pango.FontDescription.from_string only has the size so font family will be null. Maybe that's the problem.Quote  from the API: **Any one of the options may be absent. If FAMILY-LIST is absent, then the family_name field of the resulting font description will be initialized to null.**

Comment: I tried modifying that , but the result was the same. The rest of the tags are not applied.

Comment: I've used the [textview python example](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/textview.html) and i'm able to set the font with textbuffer method `create_tag` for property font where font is a string like "Mono 32". In the example i've used `self.textbuffer.create_tag("font", font="Mono 32"). This values are just an example that you must adapt to your situation. For size, i've used property size_points = <int_value> and also worked.

Comment: (Got the mobile app, was not stalking :D). The problem is not applying the size tag, but applying the rest of the tags once the font has been set. Bold, italic etc wont work if i change the font size.

Comment: I also use the mobile app ;) I'm afraid your example (code wise) isn't complete enough to recreate the problem. with the example code i can apply more than one tag to the text selection.

Comment: This is the only part of the code that applies tag. Can you post your full example on a website like jsbin or something ? This way i can compare everything

Comment: check https://pastebin.com/U4K6kcm6 the italic icon will change font and size

Comment: The issue persists though, when you apply the tag that changes the font and size and then try to bold it, it does not work. I literally copy pasted your code and when I applied the font tag, I was not able to bold it afterwards.

Comment: underline does work. Bold maybe that font doesnt have a bold variant

Comment: The thing is that the bold and italic are not applied even on other fonts that I have tested. It is weird because if I change the font for the entire buffer and then apply the tags it works :/